# Is there a way to find why the Visual Studio 2019 won't minify a js file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019, minify, webgrease

I keep getting this error

> scripts.render system.nullreferenceexception 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I've ran my code through a number of different online minifiers to see what the issue could be and my code minifies without any issue on the online minifiers, except one, and it seems to not like template strings in this one file, but my other files use template strings and minify fine, so I am at a loss. Yes, I have looked online and not found any solutions other than "use new Bundle instead of new ScriptBundle"

I use ScriptBundle in my BundleConfig, I could just use new Bundle instead, and that works, however I can't have users do a ctrl+f5 everytime they hit the app so they get the updated javascript file.

I have looked through my code and found one issue, but that was all.

my stack trace is this, and nothing is popping out at me

> System.NullReferenceException
> HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Source=WebGrease
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseArrowFunction(AstNode parameters)
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement)
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatements(Block block)
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.InternalParse()
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.Parse(DocumentContext sourceContext)
> at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyJavaScript(String source, CodeSettings codeSettings)
> at System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
> at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context) at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) at System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.EliminateDuplicatesAndResolveUrls(IEnumerable`1 refs)
> at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) at System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths) at System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(String[] paths) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__AWLayout_cshtml.Execute() in D:\Site\AWOnline\Main\AW.Framework.UI\Views\Shared\_AWLayout.cshtml:line 23 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
> at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
> at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
> at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

Comment: The first line of the stack trace is "Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseArrowFunction(AstNode parameters) at". Have you recently added an arrow function to your javascript? If so, double check the syntax? May be a bug for the maintainers of the minifier

Comment: @phuzi, Ah, Ok, let me look because I do have some arrow functions

Comment: @phuzi, I have those arrow functions littered throughout the one file and in other files that use them and the other files minify fine

Comment: If possible, I'd try commenting out/removing arrow functions and retrying the minification to try and narrow it down to a particular one.